# How to open port 465 for user

Tags: centos, port

I have the port open and working for root but it is not open for user XYZ. How can I open the port so that user XYZ can access it.

OS : Centos 6.9

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ports numbers below 1024 are [privileged](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) and non-root users can't bind to them. How you work around it depends on your situation.

Programs usually drop their extra privileges by changing to non-root user after binding to a port. If that is not an option, you could use iptables to redirect port 465 to a one in above 1024 as a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

This should allow all packets into port 465:

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 465 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT